# Why does my router have countersunk holes on its bottom plate?

Tags: router

My router has countersunk holes in its base. What am I supposed to attach between the bit and the base?

Comment: A picture would be useful to clarify your question

Comment: Agree a picture would be a great help as I think we have a confusing idea of whether this is about countersinks or actually counterbores (or both, as some [older?] router bases have holes of both types)..

Comment: The plastic base that rests on the work piece has 3 conical indentations around its central hole so that you can insert screws without their heads interfering with the work.

Comment: Those holes are usually for mounting the plastic base plate to the router base. Perhaps this is meant to fit more than one router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The large countersink that surrounds the bit is for guide bushings for template work. The smaller holes are probably for the auxiliary fence attachment.

Comment: The main hole would have a counterbore surely?

Comment: Of course it is. Changing terminology doesn't clarify to the Original Poster. Rather than muddy the waters I allowed counter sink to include counterbore.

Comment: But you could have gone over the difference (even if just with links) as part of fleshing out a more complete and comprehensive Answer of maximal help to the OP, which is rather what the site is about.